# Warning Dialog Box in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, dialog, popup

I run a very completed piece of MATLAB code containing hundreds of variables and sometimes I forget to change value of variables/parameters. I want to create a dialog box that pops up and notifies me about values of my variables prior to execution of the program.

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of the [predefined dialog boxes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/predefined-dialog-boxes.html), such as [`inputdlg`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputdlg.html). The [first example in the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputdlg.html#bqvo453) shows how you can allow the user to modify multiple values (with defaults):

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the problem with inputdlg is that it cann't fetch variable values instead it takes and passes string values only I think

Comment: @Mohsin: Yes, but that's true of *any* GUI you use. You'll have to convert the values to strings for display purposes, and convert from strings to values if using editable text boxes for input.

Comment: @Mohsin The alternative would be to just have a generic warning dialog which prompts you to look at the command window, where you have output the current value and are awaiting `input` for the  new value. Really though, `input` is doing some internal `eval` on the string input anyway, so you're no better off!